Perforce to Git migration using git-p4 having issue with the label conversion to git tags
I need to migrate a project from perforce to git, I am using git-p4 to do that, however the labels are not converted to tags.
I am using python 2.7.8 as per the requirements for git-p4
I know there are two type of labels automatic and static. The automatic labels have a @xxxx revision on them.
The labels not having this revision field are converting fine to the tags Whereas the labels having the revision field are not converting.
I am using below command while cloning and using windows operating system for this operation

py -2 "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git-p4.py" clone //pathToDepot@all --import-labels

I tried git tag command directly on perforce labels but did not worked
I am taking revision id from perforce project and searched in gitlab commits, after that created a tag using that commit and it is working fine
is there any way to automate this
